# Is there a way via API to know what AI model the specified Azure Open AI endpoint (deployment) is configured to use?

Tags: azure-openai

I'm working on an application where end users are required to bring their own Azure OpenAI subscription in order for it to work. Because of this, I am not able to check what models they have configured on their Azure OpenAI deployment. Is there a way via API call to determine what it supports?

I was originally going to use the [/models endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/azureopenaistable/models/get?tabs=HTTP) but that applies to the whole resource. In this case, since the endpoint is deployment-specific, the resource support API does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least for the case of Azure OpenAI, you can send in any value for the `model` when making a chat completion request and it'll return back whatever model was actually available to use in the response.

So if the deployment only supports `gpt-4` (8k tokens) and you send `gpt-4-32k` in the chat completion request, the response will come back with `model` set to `gpt-4`. I am able to use that response to determine what the max token count should be.

Comment: In fact it looks like sending a null `model` also doesn't break anything.